# Functors $1 \to C, 2 \to C, 3 \to C$ (McLane exercise 1.3.2)

Tags: category-theory

This is exercise 2 in Mclane's Categories For the Working Mathematician, chapter 1.3.

Show that functors $1 \to C, 2 \to C, 3 \to C$ correspond respectively to objects, arrows and composable pairs of arrows in C.

(1 is the category of one object with just the identity morphism, 2 the category of two objects a,b with a morphism $a \to b$ and 3 the category with three objects $a$, $b$, $c$ with morphisms $a \to b,b \to c, a \to c$)

My question is perhaps very simple: When defining a functor T between two categories $C$, $D$ you define an object function from objects to objects and a morphism function. The object funtion is said to assign to each object $c$ an object $Tc$. So if $C$ has less objects than $D$ (as, for example happens in the category $1$), how does the functor work? In other words, the object funtion in the exercise from $1$ to $C$ where $C$ has more than one object, is not surjective, so there are objects in $C$ that are not represented by the functor.
I know there must be a mistake in my syllogism but can you clarify it a little, maybe with an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'corresponds' just means that there is a correspondence
between e.g. the class $\text{ Ob}(C)$ of objects of $C$
and the class  $[1,C]$ of all functors from $1$ to $C$.

Likewise for the other cases.

In fact, you probably have already seen a similar statement
in the special case where the category $C$ has only identity
morphisms: elements of a class correspond to maps from a singleton
to that class.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, *one* functor $1\to C$ determines exactly *one* object in $C$, but this can be *any* object.

So, the functors $1\to C$ correspond to objects of $C$.

Comment: So, "corresponds to objects" means that every object can be determined? This can also happen with other, more "complex" categories (like 2 and 3 for example). Does it mean that it is the "least complex" category that can determine each property (objects, arrows, composable arrows)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: functions don't need to be surjective. A functor $C \to D$ does not have to "represent" every object in $D$: there is a functor that maps a field $K$ to the abelian group $K^*$ of invertible elements of $K$, but not every abelian group is the group of invertible elements of a field.

Comment: So, what does it actually mean to "correspond to " as in the exercise? That there is the possibility to "reach" from 1 every object in C, from 2 every morphism etc?

Comment: "Corresponds to" here means that the functor is determined by the corresponding information (object, arrow, composable pair of arrows).